# Query data from remote db to match data with local db

Tags: database, call

I am looking for the best way to do this...

I want to query a remote database and match that data with data in a local database. My remote is basically a financial records db that has deposits for individuals and the are identified by a unique number for each person.  The local db has that same unique number for the person.  So what I want to do is for each person, sum() the amounts and display that with data from the local db.

I was thinking I would query the remote db and get it into an array or JSON string and somehow loop through that and match it with the data from my local db.

Does that make sense at all?

Comment: Have you tried going over the manual of your RDBMS? Some of them support "federated" queries where tables in separate databases can be targeted in the SQL statement. Would be of help if you can provide details about the remote and local db: what RDBMS system are they running on?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that.  I am using a MYSQL db on both ends.  I am not sure that both MYSQLs with have federated queries support I will look into that.  I was thinking as long as I can get the data in a JSON object or something I just need a way to match that with the data in my local db.

Comment: If you can implement my answer below, that would be the straightforward solution. No need for complex and expensive movement of data and parsing!

Answer (score 1):

Since both servers are running on MySQL and assuming you have at least read access on the remote db and admin access on the local db:

1. Create a table on the local db matching the specification of the target table in remote db. Additionally, set these table options: ENGINE = FEDERATED CONNECTION = 'connection_string'
2. You can now run the query on the local db using the usual SQL.

Please see the [documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-create-connection.html)